# Swift - get size of viewController with navigation bar and tab bar

Tags: ios, swift

my viewController has both navigation and tab bars.
I need to figure out available space after subtracting size of navigation and tab bar.
I tried:

```
let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height - self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.size.height - self.tabBarController!.tabBar.frame.size.height
```

But it is not working...
Am I doing something wrong?

EDITED:
Sorry lacked information.
I want to embed UIScroll view in between Navigation and Tab bar. The equation returned height that is bigger than available space.

```
titleView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: titleWidth, height: height))
```

The titleView surpassed "tabbar.y"

Comment: What result are you getting?  Where are you calling this code?

Comment: Sorry, I added more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to also subtract height of statusBar. Damn..

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get this information is using layout guides.

`let viewHeight = view.frame.height - (topLayoutGuide.length + bottomLayoutGuide.length)`

However, I think you're much better off using Autolayout to manage the height of your scrollView instead of setting in directly.